# Javascript to get text node of td using tr class

Tags: javascript, html, class, innerhtml, tr

I have the following codes below:

```
<table>
  ...
[Multiple lines ommited for brevity]

<tr class="bibItemsEntry"> 
<td width="31%" ><!-- field 1 -->&nbsp;Archives, Thesis Col. Graduate, 12F (Mezz.) Henry Sy Sr. Hall 
</td>
<td width="46%" ><!-- field C -->&nbsp;<a href="/search~S1?/cCDTG006829/ccdtg006829/-3,-1,,E/browse">CDTG006829</a> <!-- field v --><!-- field # -->&nbsp;<!-- field ! -->&nbsp;ROOM USE ONLY</td>
<td width="23%" ><!-- field % -->&nbsp;CHECK SHELF </td></tr>
</table>

<p id="demo">Test</p>
```

What I wanted to do is to use javascript and get the first value of the text node of `<td>` under `<tr class="bibItemsHeader">`. I'm trying to put the value into `<p id="demo">`. 
I'm trying out the below javascript code:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("bibItemsEntry");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x[0].innerHTML;
```

But I'm getting all the td text node values. Can somebody help with my problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to *iterate* over the collection to get a value from each element in the collection.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: `$('#demo').html($(".bibItemsEntry").find("td:first").text())` Assuming that you are using jQuery .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting the `tr` element and not the first `td` that you really want. Try this:

```
const td = document.querySelector('.bibItemsEntry td:first-child');
const p = document.getElementById('demo');
p.innerHTML = td.textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const x = document.getElementsByClassName("bibItemsEntry")[0].firstElementChild.innerHTML;
const p = document.getElementById('demo');
p.innerHTML = td.textContent;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it's often better to add some explanation to your code. What have you done/changed that solved the problem? See [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)