# Javascript to get text node of multiple tds using tr class

Tags: javascript, html, class, innerhtml, tr

this question is somewhat related to the first question I posted here: [Javascript to get text node of td using tr class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51624839/javascript-to-get-text-node-of-td-using-tr-class)
I have the following codes below:

```
<table>
  ...
[Multiple div lines ommited for brevity]

<tr class="bibItemsEntry"> 
<td width="31%" ><!-- field 1 -->&nbsp;Archives, Thesis Col. Graduate, 12F (Mezz.) Henry Sy Sr. Hall 
</td>
<td width="46%" ><!-- field C -->&nbsp;<a href="/search~S1?/cCDTG006829/ccdtg006829/-3,-1,,E/browse">CDTG006829</a> <!-- field v --><!-- field # -->&nbsp;<!-- field ! -->&nbsp;ROOM USE ONLY</td>
<td width="23%" ><!-- field % -->&nbsp;CHECK SHELF </td></tr>
</table>

<p id="demo">Test</p>

[multiple divs <tr>s <td>s omitted for brevity]
....
<tr  class="bibItemsEntry">

<td width="31%" ><!-- field 1 -->&nbsp;Shelf 194, 10F Mezzanine (Filipiniana), Henry Sy Sr. Hall 
</td>
<td width="46%" ><!-- field C -->&nbsp;<a href="/search~S1?/cPS3568.O5333+A6+2016/cps+3568+o5333+a6+2016/-3,-1,,E/browse">PS3568.O5333 A6 2016</a> <!-- field v --><!-- field # -->&nbsp;<!-- field ! -->&nbsp;ROOM USE ONLY</td>
<td width="23%" ><!-- field % -->&nbsp;LIB USE ONLY </td></tr>
</table>
<p id="demo">Test</p>
```

What I wanted to do is to use javascript and get the first value of each occurence of the text node of `<td>` under `<tr class="bibItemsEntry">` and and put into p id=demo (That is into their respective s) . I'm trying to put the value into `<p id="demo">`. 
I'm trying out the below javascript code:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("bibItemsEntry");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x[0].innerHTML;

[benvc][1] answered the below code, thanks to him/her: 
const td = document.querySelector('.bibItemsEntry td:first-child');
const p = document.getElementById('demo');
p.innerHTML = td.textContent;
```

> it only gets the first iteration which is true enough, I was not able to put that in my first question... Thanks in advance!

Comment: _under <tr class="bibItemsHeader">_ or under tr with class `bibItemsEntry`??

Comment: note that you'll want to keep your ids unique across your html!

Comment: Hi! bibItemsEntry, just corrected the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the `x` result like :

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("bibItemsEntry");

[].forEach.call(x, function(item) {
  var demo = item.querySelector('.demo');
  var firstTd = item.querySelector('td:first-child');

  demo.textContent = firstTd.textContent;
});
```

```html
<table id="codexpl" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Demo</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bibItemsEntry">
    <td width="31%">
      <!-- field 1 -->&nbsp;Archives, Thesis Col. Graduate, 12F (Mezz.) Henry Sy Sr. Hall
    </td>
    <td width="46%">
      <!-- field C -->&nbsp;<a href="/search~S1?/cCDTG006829/ccdtg006829/-3,-1,,E/browse">CDTG006829</a>
      <!-- field v -->
      <!-- field # -->&nbsp;
      <!-- field ! -->&nbsp;ROOM USE ONLY</td>
    <td>
      <p class="demo"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bibItemsEntry">
    <td width="31%">
      <!-- field 1 -->&nbsp;Shelf 194, 10F Mezzanine (Filipiniana), Henry Sy Sr. Hall
    </td>
    <td width="46%">
      <!-- field C -->&nbsp;<a href="/search~S1?/cPS3568.O5333+A6+2016/cps+3568+o5333+a6+2016/-3,-1,,E/browse">PS3568.O5333 A6 2016</a>
      <!-- field v -->
      <!-- field # -->&nbsp;
      <!-- field ! -->&nbsp;ROOM USE ONLY</td>
    <td>
      <p class="demo"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Hi! 'input[name="fruit"]?

Comment: Thanks! Code worked, however it put all the text nodes only in the first tr not for each tr.

Comment: Do you have the `<p id="demo">Test</p>` inside every tr ?

Comment: Yes, I have inside every tr.

Comment: Ok I'll fix it using classes instead since the id should be unique in the same document

Comment: Updated, check it now, if any answer from the posted here is what you're looking for Mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Hi Thanks for taking a look! It did not show the text nodes.

Comment: Have you adjusted the `demo` elements, by changing the id to class `demo`? do you have one table of multiple tables?? please add the full HTML, so I can understand.

Comment: Hi! Adjusted the p id="demo" to p class="demo" The html code can be seen here: lib1000.dlsu.edu.ph just search anything that will yield search result, basically the same structure, I just added the p id="demo" in order to see if I can push the td node values

Comment: Ok I see, do you want the `demo` element to be inside every table (as in my example) or next to every table like `<table>...</table><p class="demo"></p><table>...</table><p class="demo"></p>...`

Comment: Either way, for as long as for each iteration I can get the text node values. But since I don't have access to edit the code inside the table, it seems the latter. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what I can do for you from here?

Comment: Thanks Zakaria! Will check again the code and do more reading. Cheers!